# Chrome console showing 2 different values for the same variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, p5.js

I've been working on a little project of mine using the P5.js library when I noticed something strange. I may be wrong about this, but I just want someone to clarify it for me if possible:

In the example I have 2 classes: a ParticleBuilder and a Particle. The ParticleBuilder class is just a class with functions to create a Particle, which is created at the end and returned:

```
class ParticleBuilder {
    constructor(){
        this.particleTypeNumber = 0;
        this.xPosition = 0;
        this.yPosition = 0;
        this.xVelocity = 0;
        this.yVelocity = 0;
        this.directionAngle = 0;
        this.speed = 0;
        this.rotationAngle = 0;
        this.displayColor = color(0);
        this.strokeWeightValue = 1;
        this.displaySize = 10;
        this.lifespanFrameCount = 60;
    }

    type(v) {
        this.particleTypeNumber = v;
        return this;
    }

    position(x, y) {
        this.xPosition = x;
        this.yPosition = y;
        return this;
    }

    polarVelocity(dir, spd) {
        this.directionAngle = dir;
        this.speed = spd;
        this.xVelocity = spd * cos(dir);
        this.yVelocity = spd * sin(dir);
        return this;
    }

    rotation(v) {
        this.rotationAngle = v;
        return this;
    }

    particleColor(v) {
        this.displayColor = v;
        return this;
    }

    weight(v) {
        this.strokeWeightValue = v;
        return this;
    }

    particleSize(v) {
        this.displaySize = v;
        return this;
    }

    lifespan(v) {
        this.lifespanFrameCount = v;
        return this;
    }

    lifespanSecond(v) {
        this.lifespan(v * IDEAL_FRAME_RATE);
        return this;
    }

    build() {
        let newParticle = system.commonParticleSet.allocate();
        newParticle.particleTypeNumber = this.particleTypeNumber;
        newParticle.xPosition = this.xPosition;
        newParticle.yPosition = this.yPosition;
        newParticle.xVelocity = this.xVelocity;
        newParticle.yVelocity = this.yVelocity;
        newParticle.directionAngle = this.directionAngle;
        newParticle.speed = this.speed;
        newParticle.rotationAngle = this.rotationAngle;
        newParticle.displayColor = this.displayColor;
        newParticle.strokeWeightValue = this.strokeWeightValue;
        newParticle.displaySize = this.displaySize;
        newParticle.lifespanFrameCount = this.lifespanFrameCount;
        return newParticle;
    }
}
```

I console logged the ParticleBuilder and the Particle itself when I'm returning newParticle, and the results I got were... unexpected to say the least.

[image]

My questions are:
 1. Why are the two classes showing different values?
 2. Why are the values in the curly braces different from the values themselves in the list. For instance xPosition is 320 on the top row and 0 in the list.

I'm fairly sure I'm doing something wrong, but for days I can't figure out what.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code where you call this class? and where you are logging to console?

Comment: This is the logging: https://prnt.sc/he8cyi
This is where the class is used: https://prnt.sc/he8db0
The builder is just simply a 'new ParticleBuilder()'

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] directly in the post? Get rid of all the code not directly related to the problem (use a simpler example with just a couple variables), and include all of the logging (we should be able to copy and paste your code to run it ourselves).

Comment: Finally, after many many tries, I managed to make a working example to show the weirdness: https://pastebin.com/gAUpas4n
Keep in mind it requires P5.js
Things started to get weird when I added the `Something` class. If i do the things from the `doSomething()` function in `setup()`, it shows the right values.